# (C# MultiProject TemplateWizard) Project Generation in SolutionFolder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, wizard, visual-studio-extensions

I develop `TemplateWizard` to generate solutions of several projects in the VS. All projects at the start of the team `dteObject.LaunchWizard (str, ref contextParams);` generated in the Solution.

How to generate the project folder in a logical folder (SolutionFolder)?

(I can provide the necessary parts of the code and information on request)

Answer (score 0):

SolutionFolder does not support adding a folder in it, you can [create a project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767.aspx) and add the project to solution folder by using [SolutionFolder.AddFromFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.solutionfolder.addsolutionfolder.aspx)